# How can I get get params in url via slashes in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to build url with get params via slashes.

For exapmle, I want this code:

```
Url::to(['/controller/action',
    'filter' => 'filter,
    'param1' => 'value1',
    'param2' => 'value2' ...]);
```

to generate url:
//path.to.site/controller/action/filter/param1/value1/param2/value2...

Is there a way to make this via defaut urlManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Yii;
use yii\web\UrlRuleInterface;

class SearchUrlRule implements UrlRuleInterface
{

    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();

        if (strpos($pathInfo, 'somepath') !== 0) {
            return false;
        }

        $parameters = explode('/', $pathInfo);

        if ($parameters[1] !== 'f') {
            return false;
        }

        $route = 'controller/action';

        $params = [
            'filter' => 'f'
        ];
        $count = count($parameters);
        $i = 2;
        var_dump($parameters);
        while (($i + 1) < $count) {
            $params[$parameters[$i]] = $parameters[$i + 1];
            $i = $i + 2;
        }

        Yii::trace("Request parsed with URL rule: action/controller", __METHOD__);

        return [$route, $params];
    }

    public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params)
    {
        if ($route !== 'controller/action') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($params['filter'] !== 'f') {
            return false;
        }
        unset($params['filter']);

        //If a parameter is defined and not empty - add it to the URL
        $url = 'somepath/f/';

        foreach ($params as $k => $param) {
            $url .= "$k/" . $param;
        }

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Here is code, that solved my problem. And in config:

```
        'rules' => [
            ...
            ['class' => 'frontend\components\SearchUrlRule'],
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        '<controller>/<action>/<filter>/param1/<param1>/param2/<param2>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Then `Url::to` will return following result:

```
Url::to([
    '/controller/action',
    'filter' => 'some-filter',
    'param1' => 'value1',
    'param2' => 'value2'
]);

// Result: http://base.url/controller/action/some-filter/param1/value1/param2/value2
```

Comment: this will work only for param1 and param2, I needed for unknown beforehand number of params.